# Adding attribute directives dynamically in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to add attribute directives dynamically to a element. How to do this ?

let say I have created a element and wants to add attribute directives "dir1", "dir2", "dir3" to that element.

```
<div dir1 dir2 dir3></div>
```

Comment: directives can't be added/removed dynamically.
Please add some code to make it more clear what you mean with attribute directives and where to add them.

Comment: You want to create a directive that adds an element dynamically.

Comment: you can't add directives to dynamically created DOM elements, you have to create a string template with directives, compile it, then query the element with @ViewChild, read more [here](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you tell me why we can't dynamically add or remove directive from the element. I mean I am totally agreed with you that Angular element is bounded with some logic and styling which can only be applied to the element during the compile time, but still I am looking for some more in-depth logical reason.