# Angular 2 Conditional attribute not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to create a conditional attribute in angular 2 I'm also using Ionic 2.
I have an input in which I would like to control the (what I think is an attribute)

My code is working fine when I'm not trying to bind it conditionally:

```
<ion-label stacked color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
```

Now I changed my component to take in a new Input isStacked and I have a function to return the string if it is stack:

```
@Input() isStacked: boolean = true;
stackedDisplay(): string {
    return this.isStacked? "stacked" : '';
}
```

and I updated my Ion label to look like this:

```
<ion-label {{stackedDisplay()}} color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
```

When I do this I get an error:

> Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{stackedDisplay()}}' is not a valid attribute name.

I looked at a few other questions on this and they say to use the attr binding:

```
<ion-label [attr.stacked]='isStacked' color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
```

when I do it this way the binding fails as well, can someone tell me how to conditionally bind this attribute?

Comment: The last one is the good one. What is the error thrown?

Comment: dynamic directives are not currently supported in Angular: see [the comments on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590289/adding-attribute-directives-dynamically-in-angular-2) for more information

Comment: It looks like the `ion-label` directive only reads the attribute in its constructor. So emil's solution is probably your only option. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/label/label.ts

Comment: Thanks! @0mpurdy does this apply to templates as well, say for instance dynamically adding child directives to a ionic list control, because that explains another issue i was having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it following way although it's not very beautiful.

```
<ion-label stacked *ngIf="isStacked" color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
<ion-label *ngIf="!isStacked" color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work as a work around for now but I would prefer if we found a way to do it conditionally, but Upvote for effort!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add attribute dynamically in angular. It's super easy with React though :D

Comment: Hmm, I'll mark you're answer correct for now then but if someone shows me a way to do it conditionally then I may switch to theirs

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the answer [@emil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45383988/6894075) gave you could do

```html
<ion-label stacked *ngIf="isStacked else notStacked" color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
<ng-template #notStacked>
  <ion-label color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
</ng-template>
```

(Inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252966/6894075) documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf))

And although it doesn't make sense to use it for a boolean value there is also [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="stacked">
  <ion-label *ngSwitchCase="true" stacked color="primary">
  <ion-label *ngSwitchDefault color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
</div>
```

If you did not want to introduce an extra level of nesting in your output you could replace `<div>` with `<ng-container>`

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y8cuwhyRThO3WEauJhQL?p=preview)